# Referencing Workbook to add new sheets based on the range of cells in the workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a  new workbook and rename the sheets   based on a range of values (A7:A14) of the cells in my first workbook.

However when I try to run the code, I am getting an error **" Run time error 9 -Subscript out of range**'. Basically it's an error indicating that the workbook I am referencing doesn't exist although I have checked over and over again to make sure I have the right address.

Following is my code

```
        Dim r as Byte
        Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
     
       For r = 1 To 8
       Set ShNew = NewBook.Worksheets.Add
       ShNew.Name = Application.Workbooks("S11_Arrays").Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A" & r + 
       6).Value  

       Next r
       End Sub
```

Is there something that I am missing here.

Comment: Try `"S11_Arrays.xlsx"` (or .xlsm, .xlsb... whatever it is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Workbooks("S11_Arrays")
```

This is not a valid workbook name.  It should probably read `Workbooks("S11_Arrays.xlsx")` or `Workbooks("S11_Arrays.xlsm")`.  Maybe even `Workbooks("S11_Arrays.csv")`, depending on the file type.

*If* this is the same workbook that the code is running from, then you can use `ThisWorkbook` instead:

```vb
ShNew.Name = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells(r+6, 1).Value
```

You can make the issue easier to see by expanding your code, and checking which line throws the error:

```vb
Dim NewBook AS Workbook, ShNew AS Worksheet
Dim wbTemp AS Workbook, wsTemp AS Worksheet, rngTemp AS Range

Dim r as Byte
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
 
For r = 1 To 8
   Set ShNew = NewBook.Worksheets.Add

   Set wbTemp = Application.Workbooks("S11_Arrays")
   Set wsTemp = wbTemp.Worksheets("Sheet6")
   Set rngTemp = wsTemp.Range("A" & r + 6)

   ShNew.Name = rngTemp.Value  
Next r
```

Comment: Thank you. I am fairly new to VBA. Still trying to get a hang of it. Much appreciated